# Thought Ubuntu was installed, when I run PC I get 'non-system disk or disk error message'

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation

I have been trying today to set up a new pc with ubuntu.

The tower is a HP ProLiant that a local computer shop gave away a while ago
The hard drive is a new 1TB drive I bought today
I tried to install ubuntu from a USB stick (I got a local computer shop to put ubuntu on there for me - they installed this thing called rufus so the usb could be used as a boot cd.

I had a few failed attempts to start installing before I realised I hadn't put the power lead into the hard drive

Then I went for the first option 'erase disk and install ubuntu' - clicked install now and it seemed to go through the installation process fine. Got to the point where it told me to restart the computer. I restarted the machine and when it came back on it went back into the installation menus and i realised the boot usb was still in. so I switched the machine off, re-installed ubuntu to be sure; after restarting i removed the usb stick as soon as the light went off. Thought it must be fine now.

Computer starts up - on first bios screen there is a line saying no disk (i had got that during installation as well) and then It went to a screen with options for setup (F9 - i think) and something else. It said 'non-system disk or disk error' There was a countdown of 4 seconds before the system rebooted and the same page was displayed.

What is happening and what to I need to do to get ubuntu up and running?

thanks for your time and help, much appreciated

Comment: Your BIOS needs to be changed to boot from disk instead of USB as its still configured.

Answer (score 1):

On occasion, this problem is caused by SSD disk.
When installed Ubuntu in grub, the system write "hd0"

Solution:

Boot from USB with live Ubuntu.

Open terminal and write:

```
sudo -i

sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

In this file search and replace `"hd0"` for `"sda"`

Note: the hard disk name for ssd is "sda"
save and restart

Answer (score 0):

On my EliteBook 8740w I just had to enable UEFI:

1. Press power button
2. Press F10
3. Go to "System Configuration" -> "Boot Options"
4. Enable UEFI and accept the warning
5. Save changes and reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this too with an HP laptop, it turns out choosing to boot from the hard drive was not enough. At boot I had to go in the menu to select my boot options with escape then F9, then select "boot from file" and then select the efi file itself in EFI/Boot/. (Assuming you’ve installed in UEFI mode and that UEFI mode is activated in your BIOS)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

download UNETBOOTIN and re-flash your Ubuntu .iso to your USB drive. in BIOS select boot from USB, or USB/CD (depending on BIOS and drive group). reboot, and proceed to install as normal.

UPDATE: I myself finally had this issue. by any chance were you using a "generic" flash drive? (Onn brand from Walmart as a personal example) I have since found out these USB drives are not compatible with bootable live installation media. Don't know the reason why. All I did was go back to Walmart and bought a Sandisk brand USB and the exact same installation method I was attempting worked PERFECTLY.